# Chrome Developer Tools, get function's return value

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I was wondering if there is the possibility to get the return value of a function without assign it to a new variable. The image below can clarify my question.

[image: http://s11.postimg.org/uqa97zfzn/Screen_Shot_2016_03_03_at_15_27_12.png]

Comment: Please don't post a picture when you can type the code.  Why are you wanting to do this?  Is it so that you can figure out the value in the developer console, without changing your code?

Comment: You're right, but since I'm using the "Chrome Debugging Protocol" I need to know the procedure, from the GUI, and then call the specific function from the API (https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/protocol/1.1/index).